# difference of either or, neither nor, both or and either and

Tags: logic

I am answering a compound proposition exercise. I need to translate a phrase to logical connectives (only ~, ^,v) but I am confused with both or and either and as there is a note  on the questionnaire that **"both" goes with "and"** while **"either" goes with "or"** does that mean that I will disregard the *or* in the first question and *and* in the second?

```
Example
1.both p or q and r
2. either p and q or r

My answer
1.p^q^r
2.pVqvr
```

I am also confused with either or and neither nor.

```
Example
1. either -6 is a positive number or 3 is a positive number
2.  neither -6 is a positive number nor 3 is a positive number

Where
: -6 is a positive number
: 3 is a positive number

My answer
1.pvq
2.~pv~q
```

Is my answer to those examples right? If wrong can you explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose that 'v' means exclusive or?

Comment: @S.Farr: i have never seen $\lor$ used to mean exclusive or.

Comment: This is an example of where writing in English is frustratingly ambiguous.  I personally would have interpreted (1) as $(p\vee q)\wedge r$ and I would have interpreted (2) as $(p\wedge q)\ominus r$ where $\ominus$ is the exclusive or.  I say this because the sentence format "both ____ and ____", (*e.g. "both this and that"*) generally connects what was in between the "both" and the "and" together with what follows the "and"... here, frustratingly, there are multiple words in the corresponding place... hence why I put parentheses around them.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: Me neither, but OPs formulation suggests so, doesn't it?

Comment: @S.Farr: I don't think so. I think Eric Wolfsey's answer correctly captures what was intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the "both" and "either" here is just to disambiguate the parentheses.  If you just say "p or q and r", that's ambiguous: do you mean "(p or q) and r" or "p or (q and r)"?  But if you put "both" at the start, that tells you it can't be the second option: "both p or (q and r)" doesn't make sense because you can't have "both x or y", only "both x and y".

So "both p or q and r" just means "(p or q) and r", or $(p\vee q)\wedge r$ in symbols.  Similarly, "either p and q or r" just means "(p and q) or r".

For your second set of examples, you are right about the first one but the second one is wrong.  "Neither p nor q" means that p and q are *both* false, whereas your proposed $\neg p\vee\neg q$ means only that *at least one* of p and q is false (since it says "p is false *or* q is false").

Comment: Thank you! It's now clear to me.